# Java 8 Optional<?> validation unwrapper in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, java-8, option-type

In my Spring Boot project when using the following validation rules in my DTO

```
@Length(max = 70)
@UnwrapValidatedValue
private Optional<String> vendorName;
```

I am getting the following exception

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000182: No validation value unwrapper is registered for type java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>
```

I can't just find anywhere how to register custom validation value unwrapper in Spring

Answer (score 3):

You should register a `ValidatedValueUnwrapper` to the validator.

The validator could be configured via the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

  <bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationPropertyMap">
      <util:map>
        <entry key="hibernate.validator.validated_value_handlers" 
               value="com.mycompany.validator.OptionalValidatedValueUnwrapper"/>
      </util:map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

or in java:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.getValidationPropertyMap().put("hibernate.validator.validated_value_handlers",
            "com.mycompany.validator.OptionalValidatedValueUnwrapper");
    return validator;
}
```

---

You could find a [proper `ValidatedValueUnwrapper` implementation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-validation/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/validation/valuehandling/OptionalValidatedValueUnwrapper.java) in the dropwizard framework (based on the `Optional` from guava).

```
public class OptionalValidatedValueUnwrapper extends ValidatedValueUnwrapper<Optional<?>> {

    private final TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();

    @Override
    public Object handleValidatedValue(final Optional<?> optional) {
        return optional.orNull();
    }

    @Override
    public Type getValidatedValueType(final Type type) {
        ResolvedType resolvedType = resolver.resolve(type);
        return resolvedType.typeParametersFor(Optional.class).get(0).getErasedType();
    }
}
```

Comment: I quickly tried like this and it does not work
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.getValidationPropertyMap().put("hibernate.validator.validated_value_handlers", "com.....OptionalValidatedValueUnwrapper");
        return validator;
    }

Comment: Strange, i have tested it and it works. I just add in the answer the java based configuration i used.

Comment: May be you could add a breakpoint here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ValidatorFactoryImpl.java#L412 and debug the validator configuration.

Comment: I am going to play with it over the weekend. It does not work for some reason. In my project I don't use hibernate at all, may be that's the reason. It may happen that spring uses some different type of validator in absence of hibernate.